# SElinux policy to grant read access to /etc/my.cnf for httpd

Tags: mysql, centos, redhat, fedora, selinux

How can I modify the `SElinux` policy to allow httpd to read `/etc/my.cnf`?

Background: My web application connects to a mysql database. Instead of hardcoding the credentials in the code, they are stored in a mysql group in `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
[my_client]
protocol = TCP
user = john
password = mypasswd
database = my_db_name
```

In the web application I can simply refer to `my_client` when connecting to the DB. This works fine in Debian/Ubuntu, but in Fedora it fails. The problem is that SElinux prevents `httpd` from reading `/etc/my.cnf` and therefore cannot resolve `my_client`. When I disable SElinux, the problem disappears.

Comment: Why not put this information in your application configuration file?

Comment: Because I am using several clients that link to libmysql. Hence `/etc/my.cnf` *is* the configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a policy to do that, you'll need to do the following to install it;

1. Create a directory called 'policy'.
2. In that directory create a file called `httpd_mysql`

Insert the following data into the file

```
policy_module(http_mysql, 1.0.0)
require {
    type httpd_t;
}
mysql_read_config(httpd_t)
```

Now run `make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile load` to add the policy.